# JavaSwing Update button based on Network Connection flag

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, flags

I have a Java swing UI where I need to disable a button on the UI if I could not detect an active internet connection.

The code function properly so far, but when I get disconnected from the internet, it does not retrigger the method to update the boolean flag.

How can I add an event on that flag to let my button consume it during the lifetime of the application?

```
public class Main {
private static JButton button;
private static boolean testButtonEnabled;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /*
             * function that returns true/false if connected to the internet
             */
            if(Utils.isConnectedToInternet()) {
                logger.debug("System is connected to the internet");
                testButtonEnabled=true;
            } else {
                logger.debug("System is not connected to the internet");
                testButtonEnabled=false;
            }

            Main window = new Main();
            window.frame.setVisible(true);  

            button = new JButton("my button");
            /* 
             * set the internet status
             */
            button.setVisible(testButtonEnabled);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *...it does not retrigger the method to update the boolean flag.* But why should it? That would only happen were it running in a loop in a dedicate thread

Comment: I'd look at using a `SwingWorker` to poll the state of the connection, if the state changes, then you could `publish` the state and the UI could pick it up and make what ever changes it needs

Comment: I'd be interested to see an implementation of this. I tried to make one the other day and found it surprisingly untrivial, ending up with an exhausted and locked-up thread pool. I confess to having abandoned it pro-tem ;)

Comment: @g00se I was able to do it. Please send my answer below. Was simpler than I expected.

Comment: A [Swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) may be appropriate.

Comment: @Abra not really. The main workload is not going to happen in the EDT. `SwingWorker` is more apt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, this code:

```
SwingWorker<Void, String>  worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>()
        {
            public Void doInBackground()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    
                    try {
                        isConnectedToInternet = Utils.isConnectedToInternet();
                        if (isConnectedToInternet) {
                            btn_online2.setEnabled(isConnectedToInternet);
                        } else {
                            btn_online2.setEnabled(isConnectedToInternet);
                        }
                        logger.debug("Internet connection status: " + isConnectedToInternet);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
```

is dangerous since it makes mutational changes to a Swing component from a background thread. While this code *may* work 95% of the time, it can fail in unpredicatable ways and at unpredicatable times. Better to only mutate Swing components *on* the event thread. For instance, even this would be better:

```
SwingWorker<Void, String>  worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                isConnectedToInternet = Utils.isConnectedToInternet();
                // note that there is no need for the if/else block
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    btn_online2.setEnabled(isConnectedToInternet);
                });
                logger.debug("Internet connection status: " + isConnectedToInternet);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
worker.execute();
```

or better still, using SwingWorker's publish/process:

```
SwingWorker<Void, Boolean>  worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                isConnectedToInternet = Utils.isConnectedToInternet();
                // note that there is no need for the if/else block
                publish(Utils.isConnectedToInternet());
                logger.debug("Internet connection status: " + isConnectedToInternet);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void process(List<Boolean> chunks) {
        for (Boolean chunk : chunks) {
            btn_online2.setEnabled(chunk);
        }
    }
};
worker.execute();
```

Answer (score -3):

I was able to resolve using the following method in the initialize() of the frame.

Adding that change part of the swingworker allowed the button to check the flag and assign it to itself whenever it changes.

Now whenever the internet is disconnected the button is disabled and whenever connected the button is enabled.

```
SwingWorker<Void, String>  worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>()
        {
            public Void doInBackground()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    
                    try {
                        isConnectedToInternet = Utils.isConnectedToInternet();
                        if (isConnectedToInternet) {
                            btn_online2.setEnabled(isConnectedToInternet);
                        } else {
                            btn_online2.setEnabled(isConnectedToInternet);
                        }
                        logger.debug("Internet connection status: " + isConnectedToInternet);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
```

Comment: This answer is not only wrong, it is dangerous. You should *never* make a Swing call such as, `btn_online2.setEnabled(isConnectedToInternet);`, directly from the doInBackground method or any background thread. This is dangerous as the code can work 95% of the time, but then fail unexpectedly and in unexpected ways. Instead, consider using a property change listener and swing property change support, or you can use the publish / process method pair.

Comment: The whole purpose of using a SwingWorker is to avoid code like this.

Comment: Also, don't allow you workers to make assumptions about your UI.  Instead, the worker should be "publishing" or returning state/information, which is then consumed by the entity which created it